# Merge two queries into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I'm not sure if I can do this in one query but I would like to.

I need all records like this:

```
SELECT a.field_1, a.field_2, b.field_3, b.field_4
  FROM tbl_a AS a, tbl_b AS b
 WHERE a.field_1 = b.field_3
```

And I would like to also exclude these records that fall into this condition:

```
IF a.field_1 IN (1,2,3,4) 
AND a.field_date < NOW()
```

UPDATE: (sorry for the confusion)

- So if field_1 equals 1,2,3 or 4 and has a date timestamp that is today I need to display the record (add to results)
- And if field_1 equals 1,2,3 or 4 and has a date timestamp that is less than today (remove it from the results).

Any ideas to get both results into one query

Notes (if this makes a difference):

- field_a can have a value a-z, 1-99 (two characters only)

Comment: You want to  include or exclude records that satisfy your second set of conditions?

Comment: You say that And "I would like to also exclude these records that fall into this condition:" and after you say "SO if field_1 equals 1,2,3 or 4 and has a date timestamp that is today I need to display the record" so it has to display or not?

Comment: Yes Include if the date is today, exclude if date is less than today, but only if the field_1 is IN 1,2,3 or 4. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I still dont understand why two querys in one? you need al the set of your first query plus the same one with the second condition?, if it is that way, you just have to use an union clause with the query i wrote below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT a.field_1, a.field_2, b.field_3, b.field_4
FROM tbl_a AS a, tbl_b AS b
WHERE a.field_1 = b.field_3
AND (
CASE WHEN a.field_1 IN (1,2,3,4) THEN
      CASE WHEN A.FIELD_DATE = NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
ELSE 1
END) = 1
```

Comment: a nested CASE, very nice. was trying a single CASE and wasn't getting anywhere

Comment: Good to hear that this helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

here's a code that should work:

```
SELECT a.field_1, a.field_2, b.field_3, b.field_4
FROM tbl_a AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_b AS b ON a.field_1 = b.field_3
WHERE 
(a.field_1 IN (1,2,3,4) AND a.field_date = NOW())
OR
(a.field_1 NOT IN (1,2,3,4))
```

Note that if a.field is unsigned int != 0 you can replace:
`a.field_1 IN (1,2,3,4)` with `a.field_1 <=4`
and `a.field_1 NOT IN (1,2,3,4)` with `a.field_1 > 4`

this will make it faster in case a large recordset was in question

Comment: This result will only product items that have a field_1 of 1,2,3 or 4.  What if the field_1 identifier is 5 or 6?  It seems like those values should be included.  I think the post is a little vague.

Comment: @N. Warfield yeah the post is vague... I edited the answer to fit the needed results

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite this with a proper JOIN, and add a NOT on the condition to exclude :

```
SELECT a.field_1, a.field_2, b.field_3, b.field_4
  FROM tbl_a AS a JOIN tbl_b AS b ON (a.field_1 = b.field_3)
WHERE NOT (a.field_1 IN (1,2,3,4) AND a.field_date < NOW())
```

Since NOT( X AND Y ) is equivalent to (NOT X) OR (NOT Y) you can rewrite this as :

```
SELECT a.field_1, a.field_2, b.field_3, b.field_4
  FROM tbl_a AS a JOIN tbl_b AS b ON (a.field_1 = b.field_3)
WHERE a.field_1 NOT IN (1,2,3,4) OR a.field_date >= NOW())
```

But we'd also need to know if any of field_1 or field_date can be NULL. If that is the case, the expression "foo NOT IN (blah)" returns NULL if foo IS NULL. So you'd need to be more specific about that.